# No Brightness control in kde

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde

I just reinstalled my arch. During KDE install, we have multiple ways to install KDE.

```
plasma (install the whole KDE)

Plasma-meta(meta pack)

Plasma-desktop( it Just provides desktop and nothing else. Minimal install).
```

Last time I went with 1st option, but this time i choose 3rd for a minimal install. And logging in almost i sorted everything except

```
brightness control

Hotkeys are not working for brightness.
```

If i install whole KDE(1st option ), everything works fine, but with 3rd, Many were missing like network and other. Somehow i managed to sort everything except above two. In settings, there is no option to control brightness. 
Any idea which package should i install from the whole Plasma Package for brightness and hotkey.

Earlier Audio control and the network was not working. So I installed 
**plasma-nm**
**plasma-pa**

And now they are working fine.

Now i unable to guess the required package for brightness control.

https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/plasma/

This is the whole plasma pack. From this bunch can anyone guess which package among those 44 would be for brightness control and brightness control hotkeys.

I want to minimal install to don't want whole `pacman -S plasma`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question since I was looking for exactly the same.
So I went thorugh the list of the plasma packages.

The screen brightness adjustment is part of power management in KDE. I guess that you don't have the Power Management option in your System Settings under Hardware?

You need to install the `powerdevil` package.
In terminal just do:
 `sudo pacman -S powerdevil` 
Just restart and you should be good to go. (This will enable and start the Power Management service on startup)
You can adjust the brightess when clicking on the Battery Icon or through your Laptop hotkeys.
 Further Brightness adjustment settings are in System Settings > Hardware > Power Management

While you're at it, if you haven't already, I'd recomend you install these aswell: `kgamma` and `kscreen`

Hope this helps

Comment: It still doesn't change brightness on my KDE Neon. btw  I already have `powerdevil` and `kscreen` installed (fresh neon install) but `kgamma` has no install candidate since `kgamma5` replaced it

Comment: But [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I could say I had the same problem. I accidentally lowered brightness to 0 from the GUI. With the screen dark one could say I was paralyzed. KDE stores it's config files at `~/.config/`. Using a suitable text editor, just access the `~/.config/powermanagementprofilesrc` file and look for the brightness level you want to change (on battery/ low battery). Type in the desired value.
The command you mentioned, involving qdbus must be specifically for KDE connect because I tried it (the full thing) and it didn't work. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Plasma 5 applet [Display Brightness Control](https://store.kde.org/p/1325685/) solved this issue for me.

I installed it with this command:

```
plasmapkg2 -u risu.brightness.bar.v1.1.plasmoid
```

I can now change the display brightness from a KDE Plasma applet in the task bar.

Answer (score 0):

As [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight) explains:

> Screen brightness might be tricky to control. On some machines physical hardware switches are missing and software solutions may not work well. However, it is generally possible to find a functional method for a given hardware

Under the hood the options how brightness is controlled on internal monitors are:

- ACPI
- setpci

There are two cli tools mentioned:

- [xbacklight](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xbacklight/)
  for Intel graphics (eg ThinkPad). [Here is a Step-by-step guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114872/1563261)
- [light](https://github.com/haikarainen/light)

they utilize [packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight#Backlight_utilities) to control keyboard light and/or react to ambient brightness